# What prevents a FTP server sending data to me?

Tags: ftp

I can connect to two independent FTP servers with the same result - the connection is timed out unable to retrieve a dir listing. A line in the Filezilla log seems relevant:
"Response: 500 I won't open a connection to 192.168.0.2 (only to 94.1.41.42)"
I have a Sky hub with cable to an ethernet switch which feeds 2 PCs. My PC is 192.168.0.2 on the LAN and 94.1.41.42 is my IP address. If I connect by WiFi instead I get the same message, with 192.168.0.7 as my LAN address. I am very much a beginner in this area (a trainee geriatric geek) and would very much appreciate a sympathetic reply explaining what might be happening here. I have tried hard to find the answer with no success.
David Johnson

Edited, responding to suggestion by @barbecue:
I have read https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration and set Filezilla for Passive mode transfer. The problem remains. The more detailed log shows the connection is established in less than 1 second, and the last few entries are:
07:04:27 1 Trace: CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
07:04:27 1 Trace: CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
07:04:27 1 Command: PASV
07:04:27 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
07:04:27 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (91,103,219,224,201,16)
07:04:27 1 Trace: CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
07:04:27 1 Trace: CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
07:04:27 1 Trace: CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
07:04:27 1 Trace: Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 192.168.0.2
07:04:27 1 Command: MLSD

HANGS HERE FOR 20 seconds

07:04:47 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
07:04:47 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
07:04:47 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
07:04:47 1 Trace: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
07:04:47 1 Trace: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
07:04:47 1 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
07:04:47 1 Status: Disconnected from server

Edited: Further attempts to solve issue unsuccessful.
After reading about port forwarding in the Sky ER115 router, I forwarded all ports from 91.103.219.224 to LAN address 192.168.0.2 but this has no effect. I am aware my ignorance may be a large part of the problem, but one has to learn somehow!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the Filezilla site configuration in to default to PASSIVE mode. That may fix your issue. From the log, it looks like you are first trying to connect in ACTIVE mode, which is failing because of NAT. It then retries in PASSIVE mode, but the connection has timed out.

Configure Filezilla Passive Mode by editing the Site and going to Transfer Settings. Check the Passive option under Transfer mode.

PASSIVE mode provides a way for the FTP client and FTP server to negotiate what port will be used for the connection, which can help when you are behind a NAT, such as your home router.

Edit: Since enabling passive mode did not resolve the issue, my guess is this is likely a problem with firewall or routing due to the service provider or the router in use. The 20 second delay after the MLSD command suggests it could be [this issue.](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11405&start=15)
Some servers apparently don't handle MLSD commands properly, and Filezilla has a strict handling of this. Another FTP client such as CoreFTP or CyberDuck might give better results.